# How to change QCursor(mouse) size in embedded linux ? (don't use QPixmap or QBitmap)

Tags: qt, embedded-linux

I use Qt 4.8 in embedded linux. I want to change  mouse cursor(QCursor) size, it's too small, but in QCursor class there is no function can change the size.

in Qt document: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcursor.html#QCursor-3

it says here that:

> Valid cursor sizes depend on the display hardware (or the underlying window system). We recommend using 32 x 32 cursors, because this size is supported on all platforms. Some platforms also support 16 x 16, 48 x 48, and 64 x 64 cursors.

so my question is: how to change the default cursor(QCursor) size in embedded linux ? I'm searching for answers on the Internet, almost no one mentioned this problem !?

(I know it can use QPixmap or QBitmap to change the cursor icon, but this is not the fundamental way.)

thanks.

Comment: What would changing cursor size accomplish, if cursor image is not changed too?

Comment: Simply set the new cursor image of appropriate size. You have to provide such an image.

Comment: set the new cursor image need to use QPixmap, but I just want to edit default value of cursor size . Is there any method ?